# Cpanel error "Missing </FilesMatch>"

Tags: .htaccess, deflate

I am using wordpress and using this code in my .htaccess :

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c> 
mod_gzip_on Yes 
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes 
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$ 
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$ mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.* 
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.* 
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.* 
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.* 
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c> 
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$"> SetOutputFilter DEFLATE </filesMatch> 
</ifModule>
```

my error in cpanel log is:

```
2013-09-16 09:32:25.889 [ERROR] [/***/public_html/.htaccess:63] Missing '</FilesMatch>'.
```

my site is: [2nafare.com](http://2nafare.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each directive needs to be on a line by itself:

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c> 
  <filesMatch "\.(js|css)$"> 
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
  </filesMatch> 
</ifModule>
```

The `</filesMatch>` was getting associated with the `SetOutputFilter`.